# Problem with Hebrew characters in username

Tags: users, user-registration, username, characters

I wrote a plugin to enable hebrew characters in usernames. This is the full code:

```
add_filter ('sanitize_user', 'hu_sanitize_user', 10, 3);

//Overrides the Wordpress sanitize_user filter to allow hebrew letters and english letters only

function hu_sanitize_user ($username, $raw_username, $strict)
{
//Strip HTML Tags
$username = wp_strip_all_tags ($raw_username);

//Remove Accents
$username = remove_accents ($username);

//Kill octets
$username = preg_replace ('|%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])|', '', $username);


//Kill entities
$username = preg_replace ('/&.+?;/', '', $username);

if ($strict){
    //Replace
    $username = preg_replace( '[\p{Hebrew}a-zA-Z]', '', $username );
}

//Remove Whitespaces
$username = trim ($username);

// Consolidate contiguous Whitespaces
$username = preg_replace ('|\s+|', ' ', $username);

return $username;
```

}

It works well, but the problem is that if the length of the username is more than 8 characters, it doesn't create a user in the users list. However, it does still send a confirmation email that the user was created - with the name and e-mail address missing from the message.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure the user is not created? have you checked the DB table and the user's admin screen?

Comment: thanks mark, but i checked even the DB and user not created.

Comment: from looking at the code it seems that if a mail was sent then the user was created. There is probably something additional here.that is not made explicit in the question.

Comment: tx again, I know that the code is good, but some how all the wordpress users that download this have the same problem, and I can't figure it out.

Comment: It doesn't make sense. WordPress only sends confirmation after having successfully inserted new user to database. I have also tested your code with underscore theme and it worked normally. In fact, your code do nothing   because `$strict` is always defaulted to `false`.

Comment: Yes is saw the strict issue maybe u can help me with that, and pls test it with hebrew character,every this else work fine, also the problem is in 8 characters and above

Comment: So you're using strict mode? Where did you turn on strict mode?

Comment: How did you go with this @DrMosko? Were you able to check strict mode as Dan mentioned above?

Comment: @TimMalone hi, how do i check?

Comment: @DrMosko If you haven't particularly turned strict mode on, it is [off by default](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_user). Try removing your `if ($strict){` check (remove the matching `}` also) to see if that helps.

Comment: @TimMalone , I tried that, but no go...

Comment: I've put explanation and possible solution for similar issue at stackoverflow
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23163053/register-usernames-in-wordpress-in-hebrew/47909264#47909264

Answer (score 1):

**This is not a complete answer, but it's an attempt at giving you some direction. Hopefully with the community here we can come up with a solution for you!**

Firstly, I've been able to replicate your issue:

1. I took your code and placed it in my theme's `functions.php` for now.
2. I removed the `if( $strict )` test
3. I tried registering an 8 character Hebrew name - it worked
4. I removed your function and tried again - it failed (this confirms your function works)
5. I added your function and tried with a 9 character Hebrew name - it *failed*

(for non-Hebrew speakers following along, I just used [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com) and translated my own name to Hebrew, then dropped characters).

When it didn't work, the error I got was:

> **ERROR:** Couldn’t register you… please contact the webmaster !

I've never seen this error before. It comes from [wp-includes/user.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/user.php#L2293). What this tell us, hunting through the order of this, is that `wp_create_user()`, and therefore `wp_insert_user()`, is either returning false or an error object.

[`wp_insert_user()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/user.php#L1337) has a heck of a lot of filters we could potentially plug into to help this work. It may be tripping up one of these.

Alternatively, it may be a database issue. [This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18928810/1982136) has some ideas for supporting Hebrew characters in a MySQL database. My table encoding was already set to `utf8_general_ci` but my database itself wasn't, so I changed that and unfortunately it didn't resolve it. I also tried running the `SET NAMES` query through [wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Running_General_Queries), but it's possible it's not meant to work like that.

### Where to from here

I'm hardly a database expert, so I'm not sure if this is a database limitation that we may end up not being able to get around. For now, I think the best chance lies in one of those filters that `wp_insert_user()` goes through.

I don't have time right *now* to hunt through these in depth and work out where it's tripping up, but hopefully this gives you a decent head start - if I can I'll come back and see what else I can find.

Comment: thanks for ur trouble, I did not get any error at all, also tried to convert string to utf 8, did DB check, but this is not the problem, Im hopeless....

Comment: @DrMosko What about the other filters that `wp_insert_user()` calls?

Comment: that wont fix the bug, but i get u for changing the approach,